# Yarn is slow and freezes when run via docker exec

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules, yarnpkg

I recently started using docker (desktop version for Windows) for my node project development. I have a docker-compose file with volume configuration to share the project source files between my host machine and docker container.

When I need to install a new mode module, I can't do that on my host machine, of course, because it's Windows and docker is Linux or something, so I run `docker exec -it my-service bash` to "get into" the docker container and then run `yarn add something` from inside it. The problem is - `yarn` runs extremely slow and freezes almost all of the time. The docker container then becomes unresponsive, I cannot cancel the `yarn` command or stop the container using `docker-compose stop`. The only way I've found to recover is to restart the whole docker engine. So then, to finally install the new module, after docker engine restarts, I delete the node_modules folder and do the same steps again. This time it's still extremely slow, but it doesn't freeze somehow and actually installs the new module. But after some time, when I need to do that again, it freezes again and I have to delete node_modules again...

I would like to find the reasons why the `yarn` command is so slow and why it freezes.

I'm new to docker, so maybe my workflow is not correct.

I tried increasing RAM limit for docker engine from 2 GB to 8 GB and CPUs limit from 1 to 8, but it had absolutely no effect on the `yarn` command behavior.

My project was using file watching with `chokidar`, so I thought maybe that could cause the problem, but disabling it had no effect either.

I also thought the problem could be the file sharing mechanism between host machine (Windows) and docker container, but if it is the case, I do not know how to fix it. I suppose I then should somehow separate node_modules from the source directory and make them private to docker container, so that they are not shared with host machine.

This is quite a severe problem, as it slows the development down a lot. Please share any of your ideas about what could be wrong. I would even consider changing my development environment to Linux if the problem was caused by the file sharing mechanism between Windows and docker container.

Comment: You should be able to just use Node directly (especially for a browser application).  Why have you introduced Docker here?

Comment: I recently asked this question myself. Well, it seems that without docker the process would be simpler, but it allows me to have completely isolated databases and node versions (in short, environments) for each of my projects, and, most importantly, it's a breeze to run the project on other machines, i.e. my other computer or my colleagues', because there's absolutely no setup overhead, which is pretty cool. So if performance and freezing issues were fixed, I think that would definitely be worth it.

Comment: We work with many different projects, old and new, using old and new versions of node, mysql and other databases, etc., so docker kinda pays off. Or maybe not... But then I just misunderstood what its actual purpose is.